# Python Capytaine with Apple Silicon M2

Tags: python, installation, arm64, apple-silicon

I am trying to install the `capytaine` package in an environment on my Apple Silicon M2 laptop.

Normally `conda install -c conda-forge capytaine` does the trick on Windows however it doesn't work on the arm64 platform, because there is currently no precompiled `capytaine` package for Apple Silicon.

After installing `Homebrew` and `miniforge`, I have tried the following workaround:

```
conda create --name dbmt
conda activate dbmt
conda install cython pybind11
pip install --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517 numpy
pip install capytaine
```

, that I have implemented from: [text](https://github.com/capytaine/capytaine/issues/190#issuecomment-1213266106) and [text](https://gist.github.com/MarkDana/a9481b8134cf38a556cf23e1e815dafb).

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Collecting capytaine
  Using cached capytaine-2.0.tar.gz (352 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      + meson setup /private/var/folders/m_/vtp3713s53l0qch2jnxxhvr40000gn/T/pip-install-nxk6kxyi/capytaine_0dea16cbc4f0451c8fe94302b30507ad /private/var/folders/m_/vtp3713s53l0qch2jnxxhvr40000gn/T/pip-install-nxk6kxyi/capytaine_0dea16cbc4f0451c8fe94302b30507ad/.mesonpy-3r5v6kea/build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=/private/var/folders/m_/vtp3713s53l0qch2jnxxhvr40000gn/T/pip-install-nxk6kxyi/capytaine_0dea16cbc4f0451c8fe94302b30507ad/.mesonpy-3r5v6kea/build/meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.0
      Source dir: /private/var/folders/m_/vtp3713s53l0qch2jnxxhvr40000gn/T/pip-install-nxk6kxyi/capytaine_0dea16cbc4f0451c8fe94302b30507ad
      Build dir: /private/var/folders/m_/vtp3713s53l0qch2jnxxhvr40000gn/T/pip-install-nxk6kxyi/capytaine_0dea16cbc4f0451c8fe94302b30507ad/.mesonpy-3r5v6kea/build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: capytaine
      Project version: 2.0
      
      ../../meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['nvfortran'], ['pgfortran'], ['ifort'], ['ifx'], ['g95']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `gfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
      Running `gfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gfortran'"
      Running `flang --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
      Running `flang -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flang'"
      Running `nvfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
      Running `nvfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nvfortran'"
      Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
      Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pgfortran'"
      Running `ifort --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
      Running `ifort -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifort'"
      Running `ifx --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
      Running `ifx -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifx'"
      Running `g95 --version` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
      Running `g95 -V` gave "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g95'"
      
      A full log can be found at /private/var/folders/m_/vtp3713s53l0qch2jnxxhvr40000gn/T/pip-install-nxk6kxyi/capytaine_0dea16cbc4f0451c8fe94302b30507ad/.mesonpy-3r5v6kea/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I beleive `capytaine` can indeed be compiled on Apple Silicon, but I can't manage to install it.

How do I overcome this issue?

Comment: Consider installing a genuine [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (not just Clang) then use it

Comment: Well evidently you don't have a Fortran compiler installed.

Comment: Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch, I set GCC as the default compiler and it worked !

Comment: I tend to miss key information on error messages... @Siguza. Thanks for pointing it out though!